# Inline install not working

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla, firefox-developer-tools

I create addon. I get code inline installing from [this site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Installing_Extensions_and_Themes_From_Web_Pages) and generate hash sha1 but Mozilla write:

> firefox block install, allow (in button)?

If I do it in my local computer all good, if in site this not working.

```js
function install (aEvent)
{
  for (var a = aEvent.target; a.href === undefined;) a = a.parentNode;
  var params = {
    "Foo": { URL: aEvent.target.href,
             Hash: aEvent.target.getAttribute("hash"),
             toString: function () { return this.URL; }
    }
  };
  InstallTrigger.install(params);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="firebug-2.0.18-fx.xpi"
hash="sha1:C7AF7F925C611EC88979FD905943584A2A891420"
onclick="return install(event);">Install Extension!</a>
```

Site: http://googlewordpad.info/moz/in.php. This addon is example!